# How can i extract only the words end with number?

Tags: javascript, regex

i am getting a info from back-end. i need to convert that in to multiple word, and to require to store in array. using `regexp` how to get that?

here is the word:

```
Enter Room/Area^_^Area 100#_#Enter Grid^_^Grid2#_#Enter Level / Building^_^Building1#_#Enter Drawing^_^Drawing1#_#Enter Spec section^_^Spec2#_#Enter BOQ^_^BOQ1#_#
```

the result should be :

```
["Area 100", "Grid2","Building1", "Drawing1", "Spec2", "BOQ1" ]
```

So simply i would like to pick the words which end with number. upto the special char `^`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\b[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\d+\b
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wZ0iA3/6

```
var re = /\b[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\d+\b/gi;
var str = 'Enter Room/Area^_^Area 100#_#Enter Grid^_^Grid2#_#Enter Level / Building^_^Building1#_#Enter Drawing^_^Drawing1#_#Enter Spec section^_^Spec2#_#Enter BOQ^_^BOQ1#_#';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```